# creating jupyter notebook in watson

Tags: jupyter-notebook, ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, api-key

while creating jupyter notebook I am getting this error. I have also created the api key. Kindly help me please I am sharing the error screenshot[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VhbFB.png)

Comment: Retry or add details on how you created the API key. Please do not include screenshots, but specify the actual error message.

Comment: https://cloud.ibm.com/iam/apikeys  I created the apikey through this link sir...